# cross database access in azure synapse sql pools

Tags: azure-synapse, cross-database

I have two synapse sql pools
PoolA and
PoolB

There is a table called Customers residing in Synpase SQL **PoolA**. Is there a way to access Customers table from Synapse SQL **PoolB**

I am exploring the option of create external data source, but couldn't the right syntax/ not sure if it supported.

Can any one help me with my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a dedicated sql pool, unfortunately there is no current feature to query cross database ( via external tables)

You can query synapse table from Azure sql database via elastic query but cannot query any database from synapse

Comment: Assuming this feature is not supported in either serverless / dedicated pool to directly access it from database.